# Contrapositive of $x=2, y=3,$ then $xy=6$

Tags: logic

[image: is the contrapositive statement true?]

Help in writing contraposition for this statement

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive of a statement $P \rightarrow Q$ is $\lnot Q \rightarrow \lnot P$. In words, *if $P$ then $Q$* has a contrapositive that reads *if not $Q$, then not $P$.*

Your statement is *if ($x=2$ and $y=3$), then $(xy=6)$.* The contrapositive is, using the form above, *if $\lnot(xy=6)$, then $\lnot (x=2 \text{ and }y=3)$.* In other words, if $xy\neq 6$, then we cannot have $x=2$ and $y=3$ --- if we did, then $xy=6$, and that would be a contradiction. So the contrapositive is true.